# Why does when I click on the map I get the map bigger using Chrome?

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am working with leaflet and when I click on the map, the map is bigger with the Chrome browser I don't know why.

Here is my code :

```
import "./styles.css";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App overflow-hidden">
        <nav className="bg-white border-gray-200 px-2 sm:px-4 py-2.5 rounded dark:bg-gray-900">
          <div className="container flex flex-wrap justify-between items-center mx-auto">
            <a href="https://flowbite.com/" className="flex items-center">
              <img
                src="https://flowbite.com/docs/images/logo.svg"
                className="mr-3 h-6 sm:h-9"
                alt="Flowbite Logo"
              />
              <span className="self-center text-xl font-semibold whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                Flowbite
              </span>
            </a>
            <button
              data-collapse-toggle="navbar-default"
              type="button"
              className="inline-flex items-center p-2 ml-3 text-sm text-gray-500 rounded-lg md:hidden hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-gray-600"
              aria-controls="navbar-default"
              aria-expanded="false"
            >
              <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
              <svg
                className="w-6 h-6"
                aria-hidden="true"
                fill="currentColor"
                viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  fillRule="evenodd"
                  d="M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 15a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1z"
                  clipRule="evenodd"
                ></path>
              </svg>
            </button>
            <div
              className="hidden w-full md:block md:w-auto"
              id="navbar-default"
            >
              <ul className="flex flex-col p-4 mt-4 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-100 md:flex-row md:space-x-8 md:mt-0 md:text-sm md:font-medium md:border-0 md:bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 md:dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700">
                <li>
                  <a
                    href="/#"
                    className="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-white bg-blue-700 rounded md:bg-transparent md:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-white"
                    aria-current="page"
                  >
                    Home
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a
                    href="/#"
                    className="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-gray-700 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-gray-400 md:dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent"
                  >
                    About
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a
                    href="/#"
                    className="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-gray-700 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-gray-400 md:dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent"
                  >
                    Services
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a
                    href="/#"
                    className="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-gray-700 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-gray-400 md:dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent"
                  >
                    Pricing
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a
                    href="/#"
                    className="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-gray-700 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-gray-400 md:dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent"
                  >
                    Contact
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div
          className="flex-wrap sm:flex-nowrap
                          items-start container flex justify-between items-center mx-auto px-2 sm:px-4 py-2.5"
        >
          <select
            id="countries"
            className="block ml-4 mr-4 mb-2 sm:mb-0 py-2 pr-4 pl-3 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
          >
            <option selected>Choose a country</option>
            <option value="US">United States</option>
            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
            <option value="FR">France</option>
            <option value="DE">Germany</option>
          </select>
          <select
            id="countries"
            className="block ml-4 mr-4 py-2 pr-4 pl-3 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
          >
            <option selected>Choose a country</option>
            <option value="US">United States</option>
            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
            <option value="FR">France</option>
            <option value="DE">Germany</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div style={{ height: "60vh" }}>
          <MapContainer
            className="m-10"
            center={[51.505, -0.09]}
            zoom={13}
            scrollWheelZoom={true}
          >
            <TileLayer
              attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
              <Popup>
                A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
              </Popup>
            </Marker>
          </MapContainer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I thought it was a problem with the property overflow so I decided to comment that line but I get the same behaviour.

You can see the full project :

[The full project](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-fog-sjyqri?file=/src/App.js:0-6576)

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work when I remove the class `overflow-hidden` in the first div.